# JavaScript behaviour when referencing a HTML data attribute that doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Today I've been looking for the best way to toggle the text of a button when clicked, for example from "Read more" to "Read less".

I came across this article on CSS Tricks https://css-tricks.com/swapping-out-text-five-different-ways/ regarding swapping out text and after deconstructing each of the methods I have a simple question regarding the behaviour of data attributes with JavaScript.

consider the following code:

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var el = $(this);
  if (el.text() == el.data("text-swap")) {
    el.text(el.data("text-original"));
  } else {
    el.data("text-original", el.text());
    el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="example-two" data-text-swap="Show">Hide</button>
```

My question relates to the use of "text-original" which is a data attribute that doesn't exist in the HTML markup. How is this code not throwing an error? I'm assuming that it works because JavaScript must somehow revert to the default html which is "Hide". Can somebody explain why this works?

Comment: Why should it throw an error? `el.data("text-original", el.text());` creates the data attribute `text-original` in the else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, JS doesn't error when directly accessing non-existent properties/attributes.

Specifically, you're using jQuery's global data cache, which integrates HTML5 `data-` attributes, and also doesn't complain when data doesn't already exist.

Either way, that technique is unnecessary because you don't need separate storage to do this, and modern browsers make it especially easy to get data attributes via the `dataset` property.

This demo uses `dataset` and destructuring assignment to make this code very short and clean.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  [this.dataset.textSwap, this.textContent] = [this.textContent, this.dataset.textSwap];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="example-two" data-text-swap="Show">Hide</button>
```

---

And of course you can do this without the jQuery dependency.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  [this.dataset.textSwap, this.textContent] = [this.textContent, this.dataset.textSwap];
});
```

```html
<button id="example-two" data-text-swap="Show">Hide</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. I'll have to do some digging into how that "de-structuring assignment" is working in your code because its not something I've seen before! But I understand now that the original code I posted was using a JQuery method.

Comment: You're welcome. Destructuring assignment is very nifty, but you can get the same thing with a temporary variable. `var temp = this.textContent; this.textContent = this.dataset.textSwap; this.dataset.textSwap = temp;`

Answer (score 1):

That's because `data-text-swap` and `data-text-original` are different things, `data-text-swap` is an HTML5 data-* attribute, while `data-text-original` is storing some data related to the element.

Basically it compares the `data-text-swap` value with the actual text value of your element, initially they'll be different and when you click the text value will change to the `data-text-swap`, saving the other one on `data-text-original`, and so on...

You can see more about it here: https://api.jquery.com/data/#data1 vs https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2

Comment: Thanks! this clarified things for me nicely.